# How can I convert a .ts file to a single .m3u8 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .ts file, but I don't have the source file(video file). I need to generate a m3u8 file from the .ts file itself without creating other .ts files. I used the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i mytsfile.ts -hls_list_size 0 mym3u8.m3u8 -hide_banner
```

When I used the above command, it has created almost 590 ts files with the name of mym3u8N.ts(where N is number from 1 to 590). I dont want ts files. I need only m3u8 file.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't have the source file". The .ts file is a video file, no? Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually the .ts file is created by mp4 file. That's why I said like that.

Comment: I don't have the original MP4 file as I told you earlier. @slhck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to generate an M3U8 file from an existing segment:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts \
-map 0 -c copy \
-f segment -segment_list out.m3u8 \
-segment_time 60 \
out%03d.ts
```

Here, it's important that you specify a `-segment_time` equal to or larger than the actual input duration, as otherwise, ffmpeg will split the input file again.

The output M3U8 will contain a reference to the newly output TS file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:61
#EXTINF:60.033333,
out000.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

You may use that, or delete the `out000.ts` file (since it's essentially the same as the input file), and change the file name in the M3U8 file, as the content of the media file will be the same.

You can do such a replacement e.g. using `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/out000.ts/input.ts'
```

I should add that for the simple case of one segment file of which you know the duration, you can easily generate the M3U8 file manually. You then have to specify the `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` and `EXTINF:` duration values manually as well.

Comment: I played the m3u8 file created by the command you mentioned, it played well. But when I delete the ts files(created by the command), the m3u8 file is not at all playing. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Of course it won't work then. As I said, you can “delete it and change the file name in the M3U8 file”. The generated M3U8 will reference the file `out000.ts`, but you have to manually change it to `input.ts`. Otherwise the player will look for the deleted file. If you open up the M3U8 file with a text editor you'll notice that there isn't much going on here—it's easy to just create it yourself.

Comment: I understood, could you please make it for me.

Comment: How do you mean, make it for you? ffmpeg already created the M3U8 file for you. I'm just saying that in case you don't want to use ffmpeg, you could write a small script or use a text editor to type the M3U8 file similar to the one that ffmpeg automatically generates. You will only have to replace the duration values and file name.

Comment: Hi, I created an m3u8 file as per you answer, but navigating through the video file(m3u8) is taking more time(almost 10 sec to play). This is very unusual. is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Are you doing this on a local computer or streaming over the Internet? What device/player are you using? Also, seeking time will depend on the keyframe interval. If it is 10 seconds or larger (which may be the case if the `.ts` that you  got was not optimized for streaming), it's expected that you're getting longer seek times. Are you okay with re-encoding the input file for proper streaming?

Comment: Actually I am testing on my local machine, later I have to stream it over the internet. But first I need to play the video(m3u8) without any delays. And Im not sure whether we can re encode the video file.

Comment: Without making this a longer discussion, I think you need to first explain how you actually want to do the streaming, what the clients should be, what the requirements are, etc. I think we don't have enough information to be able to answer your question, but you may ask a new one and be more detailed. https://superuser.com/questions/ask